# создать проект на angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать проект на angular2. Раньше я делал так:

```
ng new project_name
```

в результате создавался проект на angular2 с соответствующими зависимостями в `package.json`.

Но после выхода angular 4 , описанная выше команда создаёт проект на angular4. В этом проблема.

Comment: А в чем проблема начинать проект на angular 4? Там нет существенных отличий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вкратце:** *измените зависимости в package.json -> на зависимости от версии 2.4.1 и пересоберите проект.*

**Детализированный ответ** :

1) Создайте новый проект через angular cli.

```
ng new my-newapp
```

2) Перейдите в каталог нового проекта

```
cd my-newapp
```

3) Обновите зависимости в package.json. Измените в редакторе версию angular на 2.4.1 и версию роутера на 3.4.1

пример:-

```
{
  "name": "my-newapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

4) переустановите зависимости из npm ( опционально:- перед выполнением этой команды можно удалить каталог node-module чтобы процесс прошел чисто)

```
npm i
```

5) проверка работоспособности в браузере (localhost:4200)

```
ng s
```